# If a set has infinite measure is it NOT lebesgue measurable? If so why?

Tags: measure-theory

The definition I have been given for Lebsgue measureable sets is the following:

The sets E for which $\mu E $ is defined, that is for which $\theta A = \theta(AnE) +  \theta (A|E) $ for every A contained the reals are called Lebesgue measurable set.

(I assume this definition is following Catheradorys Method)

From this I thought if E had infinite measure than it would be hard to define $\ \theta(A|E) $.

Can somebody please explain this definition to me as I don't think I fully understand it. How does one know when a set is measurable/Lebesgue measureable?

Thanks!

Comment: From the definitions I know, set of infinite measure can be measurable. It's intersections with intervals of the form $[-n,n]$ must be measurable though.

Comment: @Martin Argerami:  no, that set $F$ is not measurable, and it also does not have infinite measure, because it has no measure at all.  If we say that a set has "infinite measure", this implies that the set is measurable. I am not sure what the OP is asking, however.

Comment: Notice that it does not make sense to speak about the measure of a subset if it isn’t measurable. And yes, there are Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with infinite measure, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner I see my contradiction of words. Does measureable = Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @CarlMummert: good point!

Answer (score 4):

A set can have infinite outer measure, without actually being measurable. As you wrote, a set $E$ is (Lebesgue) measurable if, for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, 
$$
\lambda^*(A) = \lambda^*(A \cap E) + \lambda^*(A \cap E^c).$$
Here $\lambda^*$ is the (Lebesgue) outer measure.  When we talk about "measurable" subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, unless some other measure is mentioned, we are talking about Lebesgue measure.  The outer measure is defined for *every* subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider the example mentioned by another user in the comments above: let $F$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ and let $E = F \cup [2,\infty)$.

Then $E$ has infinite outer measure, as we can prove. We can also prove that $G = (-\infty, 1]$ is measurable, and that the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable. Therefore, if $E$ was measurable then $E \cap G = F$ would also be measurable. This is impossible, so $E$ cannot be measurable.